# how to add metadata to transport stream?

Tags: metadata, transport-stream

I would like to add metadata to video H.264 using mpeg-ts (transport stream).
I know SMPTE 601.5 standard define how metadata should be used with video format.

Is there any library which support this issue ?

Comment: What do you mean by `metadata` ? are they private data or are they part of the standard ? Please clarify.

Comment: I mean KLV metadata, which is also described in MISB 336M, or MISB 601.5/601.7.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.gwg.nga.mil/misb/docs/rp/RP080403.pdf) could help

Answer (score 3):

Initially, I too having the same kind of questions during metadata tagging work with `H.264` stream. Finally I got clear picture after implementation.

> What does it mean to add metadata to raw H.264 ?

Here, two kinds of adding are there:

1. If the metadata is an Identification string, you need to insert this into the `SEI` message portion of `H.264` stream.
2. If the metadata is related to the type of particular video frame, for eg: mission, security or platform, then you need to tag this in `KLV` format to the corresponding video frame with appropriate timestamp.

The 2nd point can be easily implemented if you already implemented `KLV` encoder. `KlvLib` source is one of the best example to start up.

Comment: Thanks, is this library is part of ffmpeg package ? Thanks